# How to load A DataTable with computed column?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datareader

I have two DataSets with identical tables.

DataSet1

[image]

DataSet2

[image]

"FullName" column of both tables have expression property set as

```
[Grade]+'-'+[Class]
```

For DataSet2 I have defined a method - "Import".

```
// DataSet2.cs file

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public partial class DataSet2
    {
        public void Import(DataSet1 dataSet1)
        {
            this.Group.Load(dataSet1.Group.CreateDataReader());
        }
    }
}
```

The last line of code below (`dataSet2.Import(dataSet1);`) is throwing InvalidOperationException.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
            dataSet1.Group.AddGroupRow(1, "A");
            dataSet1.Group.AddGroupRow(1, "B");

            DataSet2 dataSet2 = new DataSet2();
            dataSet2.Import(dataSet1);
        }
    }
}
```

That's because "FullName" column is computed column. I'd like to know **how to bypass this exception in this particular situation? Is it possible to make the DataReader skip computed columns while loading? Or maybe there are some other "tricks"?**.

This is a reproduction of a problem in one of my projects with DataSets, with several Tables in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `CreateDataReader`, instead use `WriteXml` and `ReadXml`:

```
var ds1 = new DataSet1();
ds1.DataTable1.Rows.Add(1, "One");
ds1.DataTable1.Rows.Add(2, "Two");
var ds2 = new DataSet2();
using(var s= new MemoryStream())
{
    ds1.DataTable1.WriteXml(s);
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ds2.DataTable1.ReadXml(s);
}
```

In above method, since I've used the same stream for write and read, I need to reset the stream poition, so the read statement can read from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify import function as following

```
 public void Import(DataSet1 dataSet1)
        {
            //this.Group.Load(dataSet1.Group.CreateDataReader());
            foreach(var group in dataSet1.Group)
            {
                GroupRow g  =this.Group.NewGroupRow();
                g.Class = group.Class;
                g.Grade = group.Grade;
                this.Group.AddGroupRow(g);
            }
        }
```

because load function used to import all columns and can't be used if you have computed column.